# why NSAllowsArbitraryLoads not works in iOS 10.2 and above but works in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview

i am trying to load https(host url) url which contains http within it on UIWebView with making "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" as true, and it works fine on iOS 9 to load non secure http url, but in iOS 10.2 and above it is not loading. Am i missing some thing or is it stopped supporting after iOS 10.2 and above.

Comment: In iOS 10 and later, and macOS 10.12 and later, the value of [the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads] key is ignored if any of the following keys are present in your app’s Info.plist file:

NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia
NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent
NSAllowsLocalNetworking

Comment: No chance of this attributes being added?

Comment: I have as below in my plist   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
   <key>my domain.com</key>
   <dict>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
   </dict>
  </dict>
 </dict>

Comment: None of these (NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent NSAllowsLocalNetworking) are present in my Info.plist

Comment: when i see it in safari Console then it gives [blocked] "The page, was not allowed to display insecure content from" message as warning.